# Wait for input filed changed and then call a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I have simple form with input fields. I want to wait to field completely changed and then call function just one, because if input contains, for example, 15 letters I call function to change header 15 times, I tried with setTimeot but it doesn't work

my function is:

```
    changeCity = (e) => {
    let storedHeader = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offer_header'))
      if(storedHeader !== null) {
        let updatedHeader = {
            id : storedHeader.id,
            customer : storedHeader === null ? this.state.customer : storedHeader.customer,
            address : storedHeader === null ? this.state.address : storedHeader.address,
            city : e.target.value,
            date : storedHeader === null ? moment(this.state.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00") : moment(storedHeader.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"),
            price : parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('offer_header_price')),
            tax : parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('offer_header_price')) * 0.21,
            total : parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('offer_header_price')),
        }
         this.props.editHeaderDB(updatedHeader)
    }
    this.setState({
        city: e.target.value
    })
}

 <Col className="pr-md-1" md="3">
    <FormGroup>
       <label className="addOfferLabel">Grad</label>
       <Input style={{'fontSize':'14px'}}
              type="text"
              value={this.state.city || (storedHeader === null ? "" : storedHeader.city)}
              onChange={this.changeCity}
              onKeyDown={this.focusCity}
              innerRef={(input) => {this.inputCity = input}}
              onFocus={(e)=>e.target.select()}
        />
     </FormGroup>
  </Col>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for debounced behaviour.

One could use lodash debounce for this purpose. Explanation and example [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
    
...      

onChange = debounce(
  (e) => {
     // callYourFunction
  },
  delayInMilliSecs, // 500
  options, // { leading: false, trailing: true, }
);

...


<Input style={{'fontSize':'14px'}}
...
  onChange={this.onChange}
...
/>
```